# How to define the number of minor ticks in matplotlib config file

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using one `Locator()` one can control the number of minor or major ticks on a matplotlib axes.

For example :

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))
```

But the above line depends on the data you are plotting.

I would like to know if there is a way to change the number of minor ticks from a matplotlib style file such as `matplotlibrc` (https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html). For example, you can manage the minor ticks style with:

```
xtick.minor.visible : True
xtick.minor.width   : 2
xtick.minor.size    : 5
```

But I do not know how to deal with the number of minor ticks.

Comment: The number of ticks is not really considered a "style" attribute. So you currently have no choice of using an rc file for this.

Comment: Yes it is true but whatever my plot (no log axes), I always obtain 3 minor ticks between major ticks. Thus I wonder from where comes this default number.

Answer (score 2):

The number of ticks is not really considered a "style" attribute. So you currently have no choice of using an rc file for this.

As to where the default settings come from, this is determined by the [`AutoMinorLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator), which is used if no other custom locator is given and the minor ticks are turned on.

> `matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator(n=None)`
>
> Dynamically find minor tick positions based on the positions of major ticks. The scale must be linear with major ticks evenly spaced.
>
> `n` is the number of subdivisions of the interval between major ticks; e.g., n=2 will place a single minor tick midway between major ticks.
>
> If `n` is omitted or None, it will be set to 5 or 4.

This leaves room for the following workaround. You may monkey patch the `AutoMinorLocator` to use a different default than usual. E.g. to have 23 minor bins,

```
# use these lines on top of your matplotlib script
import matplotlib.ticker
class MyLocator(matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator):
    def __init__(self, n=23):
        super().__init__(n=n)
matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator = MyLocator        
 

# Now use matplotlib as usual.       
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["xtick.minor.visible"] =  True

plt.plot([1,2])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that there is a bug though, which makes both x and y axis minor ticks visible upon setting `xtick.minor.visible` to `True`. I already proposed [a fix](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12938).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator(2))
```

where `ax` is your axes and `2` is the number of minor ticks, which you can replace to your liking.